# send selected values of select box to PHP as string

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I'm using [Select2 3.4.5](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) for create select boxes,

I use this code for creatre a Multi-Value Select Boxe and everything is fine.

```
<select id="e1" name="mydata" multiple>
  <option value="D1">Data1</option>
  <option value="D2">Data2</option>
  <option value="D3">Data3</option>
</select>

...

<script>
     $("#e1").select2();
</script>
```

For get multiple selected values of select box in php I have to modify `name="mydata"` by `name="mydata[]"`, and in `PHP` I get values by this code:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST['mydata'] as $names) {
    print "You are selected $names<br/>";
}

?>
```

But my question: How can I send selected values of select box to PHP as **string** to recover in php like this : `'D1,D2,D3'` , and thanks.

**Edit:**

> I want to send the data as string, not receive it as an array then
>   change it as string

Comment: @DainisAbols Select2 makes it attractive. It's not actually relevant to the question.

Comment: Just use [implode()](http://php.net/function.implode)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Server-side with PHP**

Ideally you would do this with PHP once the value is sent. To convert the selected items just want to [implode](http://php.net/function.implode) the array

```
$names=implode(',', $_POST['mydata']);
```

Where `$_POST['mydata']` is an array

```
[0]=>'D1',
[1]=>'D2',
[2]=>'D3'
```

`implode(',', $_POST['mydata'])` would be `'D1,D2,D3'`

**Client-side with jQuery**

Your title says "send selected values of select box to PHP as string". You would do that in JS by catching the submit event of the form and using [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to change the value of that field.

```
$('#formid').on('submit', function(){
    $('#e1').val($('#e1').val().join(','));
});
```

Your form (not given) would need an id `<form id="formid" ...>`

Comment: I want to send the data as string, not receive it as an array then change it as string

Comment: I gave that option too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a client-side solution, try getting the `val()` and calling `join()`:

```
$('#e1').val().join()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gwgLV/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with javascript.

```
 <select id="e1" name="mydata" multiple>
  <option value="D1">Data1</option>
  <option value="D2">Data2</option>
  <option value="D3">Data3</option>
</select>
<button id="but" onclick="now()">Show selected values</button>
```

javascript code

```
function getSelectValues(select) {
      var result = [];
      var options = select && select.options;
      var opt;

      for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
           opt = options[i];

           if (opt.selected) {
                 result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
           }
      }
      return result;
 }

 function now(){
     var el =  document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
     var x = getSelectValues(el);
     alert(x);
 }
```

[Demo here](http://jsbin.com/ezafineh/2/)

Instead of alert store in a variable and send it along with the rest of the form data. Or you can use join (as mentioned in other answers ) to send it over post to php.