# SELECT2 - save and load selected values from dropdown in/from database

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-select2

I have an HTML/PHP form for saving/editing employee data using jQuery and jQueryUI. A field contains the organizations, which is a [jQuery SELECT2 dropdown](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/retrieving-selections) generated from all possible values of out of an SQL database.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#organisationDropdown').select2({
        placeholder: 'Wählen Sie eine oder mehr Organisationen aus'
    });

});
```

...

```
<form id="dataForm" method="post" action="mitarbeiter_speichern.php" onsubmit="return checkDataForm();">
    <table id="tabelleFelderBearbeiten" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
        <tr> 
                <td>Zugehörige Organisation</td>
                <td><select name="organisationDropdown" id="organisationDropdown" multiple="multiple">
                    <?php 
                    $resOrganisationen = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM organisation");
                    while($rowOrganisation = $resOrganisationen->fetch_array()) {
                    echo("<option value=\"" . $rowOrganisation['orgID'] . "\">" . $rowOrganisation['org_name1'] . " | " . $rowOrganisation['org_name2'] . "</option>");
                    };
                    ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

One employee could be allocated to 1-n different organizations. This is saved as an allocation table in MySQL like this:

```
+++OrgID+++employeeID+++
+++ 1           +++ 4 +++
+++ 1           +++ 7 +++
+++ 2           +++ 2 +++
...
```

In case of a new employee, I need to save the selected values into the database in the format shown above. `My thoughts: for-each *selected value* { get *selected orgID from the dropdown and INSERT INTO table}.`
I managed to get the selected values (OrgID) in an alert box using this function

```
alert("Selected value is: "+$("#organisationDropdown").select2("val"));
```

But I have no clue how to save these values into my database.

In case of editing an employee, I need to load the selected organizations for the given employeeID into the SELECT2 dropdown, and finally save changes to the data base again. My thoughts: `for-each *selected value* { get *selected orgID from the dropdown and UPDATE table, where employeeID = *selected employee*}.`
Further: How can I make sure that an update is saved correctly? In case that an employee changes an organization (delete), the deletion of the old entry should be done after a newly selected organization is saved.

I have read many topics here about saving SELECT2 values, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801924/send-selected-values-of-select-box-to-php-as-string). However, I did not find any that works in a way I need it.

Comment: 1.0 You can do all those things with just PHP and Mysql. 2.0 Its complicated archieving all your wishes with just one form / page. 3.0 e.g. A save employee page is the answer to saving new employees or an edit employee page is the answer for editing( updating ) employee data. An employee page will confirm to you that the updated data has been saved

Comment: Thank you @hans-könig for your thoughts. I do have a emplpyee-saving php file, which uses if conditions to check if a orgId is already given (update) or not (new). This works very well so far for all other fields.
I think the main question is: How can I get the values from the js alert-box into a PHP variable.